# Typed generic DAO and Entity

Tags: java, generics, dao

currently I'm trying to implement [a typed generic DAO](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects#A_Better_typed_Generic_DAO_You_decide).

I  do not even get to compile anything, since NetBeans complains about `UserDAOHibernate`

> interface expected here
>   type argument User is not within bounds of type-variable ENTITY

I'm afraid there is some obvious mistake in how I use inheritance/interfaces, since I'm rather new to Java.

Here's some stripped down code

```java
public interface GenericEntity<ID extends Serializable> {
    public abstract ID getId();
    public abstract void setId(final ID id);
}

public abstract class LongEntity implements GenericEntity<Long> {
    protected Long id;
    public Long getId();
    public void setId(final Long id);
}

public class User extends LongEntity implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Customer customer;
}

public interface GenericDAO<ENTITY extends GenericEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> {
    public abstract ENTITY findById(ID id);
    public abstract List<ENTITY> findAll();
    public abstract ENTITY makePersistent(ENTITY entity);
    public abstract void makeTransient(ENTITY entity);
}

public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<ENTITY extends GenericEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable>
        implements GenericDAO<ENTITY, ID> {
}

public class UserDAOHibernate implements GenericHibernateDAO<User, LongEntity> {
}
```

Is it that `LongEntity` should `extend GenericEntity<Long>`? If so, how would I do this with Java's single level or inheritance?

Is this layered approach a bad example to follow? All my entities need an id and this implementation could easily be reused lateron with different id types, so I thought I might use it.

Comment: Sidenote: you don't have to declare interface methods abstract (nor public) - they implicitly are public and abstract anyways. :)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks as well. Saves me another few keystrokes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from here:

```
public class UserDAOHibernate implements GenericHibernateDAO<User, LongEntity> {
}
```

You've specified that `GenericHibernateDAO`'s `ID` parameterized type is bounded by `<ID extends Serializable>`.

`LongEntity` extends `GenericEntity`, and hence, why you have a type mismatch.

Also, `GenericHibernateDAO` is an abstract class (and not an interface), so you'll need to `extends` instead of `implements`.

The correct solution should be:

```
public class UserDAOHibernate extends GenericHibernateDAO<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There was another error about implements vs. extends: `public class UserDAOHibernate extends GenericHibernateDAO<User, Long>`